# List RavenDB collections, using py-ravendb

Tags: python, ravendb, ravendb5

I'm trying to query or list all collections in a RavenDB database, using [RavenDB's Python Client](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-python-client).

So far I've come to something like:

```py
URLS = ['http://localhost:8080']
DB_NAME = 'my-db'

store = DocumentStore(URLS, DB_NAME)
store.initialize()

with store.open_session() as session:
    collections = session.advanced.document_store.database_commands.get_collections(0, 50)
```

The last line errors out with:

> AttributeError: 'DocumentStore' object has no attribute 'database_commands'

Obviously the `database_commands` isn't available. But how can I list all collections in a RavenDB v5.4+ database instead, using py-ravendb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the **maintenance operation** `GetCollectionStatisticsOperation`. 
It will give you class `CollectionStatistics` which has property `collections`.

Operation definition is in:
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-python-client/blob/b2eccad9e183c8988bb2bed808e5b3807c8a4081/ravendb/documents/operations/statistics.py#L63

A sample code that calls a maintenance operation can be found here:
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-python-client/blob/b2eccad9e183c8988bb2bed808e5b3807c8a4081/ravendb/tests/operations_tests/test_maintenance_operations.py#L19

Note: that example demonstrates sending another operation,

but... follow it and use something like:

`self.store.maintenance.send(GetCollectionStatisticsOperation())`

It should return you **stats about the default database** defined in your store.

And one of the stats props is [Collections](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-python-client/blob/b2eccad9e183c8988bb2bed808e5b3807c8a4081/ravendb/documents/operations/statistics.py#L52)